# Can you edit work orders in the field service app?

Tags: mobile

I know you can edit records (including Work orders) in Salesforce1 but when i am trialling Field Service I cannot edit a Work order.

My user is now set to the System Administrator profile so I can't believe their are missing permissions.

The documentation states with the app you:

> The mobile solution provides access to critical information regardless of connectivity, and uses automated processes to support a
>   full range of fi eld activities, from sending and receiving real-time
>   job updates to managing work orders and speeding up manual
>   administrative work. It even enables  users to generate reports,
>   access knowledge articles, update parts  required, and capture a
>   customer’s signature.

It states "managing work orders" as a feature but I can only see features for creating a service report, a new task, opening in salesforce1, adding to the feed and getting directions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

There are a few ways, the simplest being:

1. In setup go to "field service mobile settings"
2. Select "Show Edit Full Record"

The other options are to use Quick Actions, for example: [empowering users with quick actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_quick_actions.htm&type=0)

Comment: Thanks, it's so obvious - I must have looked at that page a few times.  I think we will aim to use quick actions for better control but until then the edit full record mode is useful.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks! this has helped.